# Why does my one to many relationship seem to require that I traverse the collections during session?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an application with a one to many relationship. When I do a fetch I find that I have to read the collection(s) before I return the data from my dao and the session ends or else I lose the data and get a no active session error when I attempt to read the data in my user layer. Why is this and is there a way around it? It seems like an awfully expensive aspect of Hibernate. I'm sure there're some articles explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options instead of reading all collection items before returning the object:
1. Use Eager fetch mode instead of Lazy.
e.g @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
2. Guarantee the invocation of reading these collection items of the object within the same transaction of fetching that object.

Regards,
Thinh

Comment: I'm doing a web application with Spring and using SessionFactory. What's the best way to guarantee the transaction after I've executed my dao. Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm a beginner.